# loop through variable names with for each

Tags: r

I have a database of 600 individuals (ind) sampled 12 times during their follow-up.

The acronym of the bacteria (COLI, KPN)was entered each time the sample was positive.

For each sample, there might be 3 bacteria present in the same sample (sample1_1, sample1_2, sample1_3...sample12_1, sample12_2, sample12_3)

I want to sum the number of a specifis bacteria for each individual
for example for coli and kpn (nb_coli, nb_kpn), I tried something:
[Database with expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi5y1.png)

```
for (i in 1:12) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    data_1 <-
      data %>%
      mutate(coli[i] = ifelse(sample[i]_[j] == "COLI", 1, 0))
  } %>%
    mutate(kpn[i] = ifelse(sample[i]_[j] == "KPN", 1, 0))
}

for (i in 1:12) {
  data_clean <- data1 %>% 
                    mutate(nb_coli = sum(coli[i]) %>% 
                    nb_kpn = sum(kpn[i])
```

thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Please provide a  minimal example of your data and of the desired output.

Comment: You might want to use `c_across`, see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html#per-row-summary-statistics-1)

Answer (score 0):

Its good practice to have a data frame with the raw data and another one with the counts. Furthermore, long data helps a lot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <-
  tribble(
  ~individual, ~ sample_1_1, ~sample1_2, ~sample12_1, ~sample_12_2,
  "ind1", "COLI", "KPN", "COLI", NA,
  "ind2", "COLI", "KPN", "KPN", NA,
)
data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   individual sample_1_1 sample1_2 sample12_1 sample_12_2
#>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <lgl>      
#> 1 ind1       COLI       KPN       COLI       NA         
#> 2 ind2       COLI       KPN       KPN        NA

data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("sample"), names_to = "sample_name", values_to = "sample_value") %>%
  count(individual, sample_value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sample_value, values_from = n)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   individual  COLI   KPN  `NA`
#>   <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 ind1           2     1     1
#> 2 ind2           1     2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much! It works perfectly!

Comment: just a quick question: where does "n" comes from?                          
      pivot_wider(names_from = sample_value, values_from = n)

Comment: `n` will be the counts being added by the function `counts`